# Hibernate mapping with multiple child classes and getting the super parent data from least child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a requirement like: I have 3 classes A, B, and C. From A to B OnetoMany Mapping and B to C ManytoMany  Mapping. I need a BC join table with a date column and I want the list of A based on BC created Date.

Can Anyone Help Me On this?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking how to make a custom query for a particular method in your repository class?  Look here: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-the-query-annotation/